# How do you manually add a RSS feed to IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rss, url

I need to add a RSS feed manually to IE8 (i.e. not using the orange button).  I just want to be able to input the URL.

**Edit:**  While my specific problem has gone away, this question still needs an answer (though I suspect it isn't possible).

Comment: wow crazy... I've looked around, but I don't think that's possible. I don't use IE, so I didn't know this, but now I know again *why* I don't use it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would be interested in why you want to do this -

That being said, if you are talking about from a developer point of view, you may be better off asking on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), however if you are just talking about one offs, then simply type the full XML/RSS feed address into the address bar - such as - "https://superuser.com/feeds"

You should then have the subscribe buttons.

The actual location is

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Feeds
```

However, I am not sure how it is encoded or how you can manually add to them.

Comment: I want to do it because IE8 won't recognize the StackOverflow Blog RSS feed, so it doesn't give me a subscribe button.  I want to manually enter the URL to see if that works.

Comment: I took a look at the Feeds directory, but it's all encoded stuff.  I could use a hex editor and figure it all out, but it's probably not worth that much time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds Seems to work fine for me - Try clearing your cache and the usual stuff. IF this is a specific bug, maybe post on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I see the IE8 feed button at http://blog.stackoverflow.com and pasting http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/ into the address bar works too (IE8 on XP)

Comment: @Wil, I don't have a problem with other sites (including Coding Horror), just the SO blog site.  @pelms, Yes, I misspoke in the first comment.  I get the orange button, but when I press it I get the following error page, 'Internet Explorer cannot display this feed'.

Answer (score 2):

I currently have this problem myself (I'm using IE 11 Consumer Preview on Windows 7 Pro). The only solution that I know of is to export the Feeds (File --> Import and Export) to an OPML file, manually edit that to include the feed you desire since it is human-readable, and import it back in. That's what I'm going to try.

By the way, on Windows 7 you can use %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Feeds to see the raw feed files.